"Bad access token" whenever I tried to login using Facebook credential
Appreciate if someone can help cause I am struggled solving this issue for almost 5 days. I tried all the threads here and in another forum without success.
I am trying to use the credential of Facebook to login in to my application.
I created account on firebase, and Facebook developer and I provide Ann necessary input to proceed.
on my application, I use this function which will be trigged once I clock on login button:
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginKit.FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginKit.LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: (any Error)?) {
    
    guard let token = result?.token?.tokenString else {
        print("User failed to login in with facebook")
        return
    }
    
    let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token)
    
    FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { [weak self] authResult, error in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        
        guard authResult != nil, error == nil else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Facebook credential login failed, MFA may be needed - \(error)")
            }
            
            return
        }
        
        print("Successfully login")
        strongSelf.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

before anything, just by pressing on the button, it will direct me to Facebook with the below notes:

If you are not using Limited Login, you will need to handle all Graph API calls using Graph API, iOS. The access token will not be valid. To learn more about changes to the Facebook SDK for iOS and how you can continue using the Facebook Login SDK, visit the blog.

After login in, the error when I logged in is the follow:
Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17004 "Bad access token" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, NSLocalizedDescription=Bad access token}

in Firebase, authentication tab, I provide the app ID Facebook and app secret code.
in the info.list, I open it as source code, and provide the input below:
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb1183972462675995</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1183972462675995</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>My app</string>

I am not sure what I am missing or what mistake I did.
if anyone can support in this, it would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance for all.

I get the same thing today. Have you found any source?

This works for me on flutter, you can implement something similar to swift. The problem was in nonce. I generate nonce and that fixed the error.
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';

String _generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
    const charset =
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
    final random = Random.secure();
    return List.generate(length, (_) => 
      charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)]).join();
}

String _sha256ofString(String input) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
    final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
}

Future<UserCredential> facebookSignIn() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
         final rawNonce = _generateNonce();
         final nonce = _sha256ofString(rawNonce);
         final LoginResult loginToken = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
             loginTracking: LoginTracking.limited,
             nonce: nonce,
         );
         final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
             OAuthProvider('facebook.com').credential(
                 idToken: loginToken.accessToken!.tokenString,
                 rawNonce: rawNonce,
             );
         return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
    }
}

